# Derivation from grammar

Tags: formal-grammars

Given the grammar $G=(\{S, L_x, R_x, W_x\}, \{a,b\}, P, S)$ derive the words $abaaba$ and $aabbaabb$.
$$
P=\left\{
\begin{align}S\phantom{{}_x R_y}    &\to  \epsilon \mid L_x R_x,\\
    L_x \phantom{R_y}      &\to  x \mid L_x y W_y,\\
    W_x y\phantom{{}_y}    &\to  y W_x,\\
    W_x R_y                &\to  R_y x,\\
    R_x \phantom{R_y}      &\to  x \\
\end{align}\right\}$$
with $x,y$ element of $\{a,b\}$. ($x$ and $y$ may or may not be equal)

Following the rules I always end up with words of the form $xx, xyxy, xyyxyy, \ldots$.
Am I allowed to replace each $y$ differently? Otherwise I don't see any way to get words like $abaaba$.

Comment: (um - $W_y$ never reduces to terminals. And subscripting $W$ doesn't seem justified. And neither $W_y$ nor $R_y$ appear in the set of non-terminals.)

Comment: I know, but that's the way the task was given to me. I'm glad not to be the only one who's irritated by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar as given in your assignment is an abbreviation for the following expanded grammar:

$$P=\left \{
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
S &\to \epsilon, \\
S &\to L_a R_a, \\
S &\to L_b R_b, \\ \\
L_a &\to a, \\
L_a &\to L_a a W_a, \\
L_a &\to L_a b W_b, \\ \\
L_b &\to b, \\
L_b &\to L_b a W_a, \\
L_b &\to L_b b W_b, \\
\end{aligned}\qquad\begin{aligned}
W_a a &\to a W_a, \\
W_a b &\to b W_a, \\
W_b a &\to a W_b, \\
W_b b &\to b W_b, \\[8pt]
W_a R_a &\to R_a a, \\
W_a R_b &\to R_b a, \\
W_b R_a &\to R_a b, \\
W_b R_b &\to R_b b, \\[8pt]
R_a &\to  a\\
R_b &\to  b\\
\end{aligned}\end{align}\right \}$$

So, yes, $x$ and $y$ need to be replaced consistently when you expand the shorthand notation. (And it's probably clear why the shorthand was used.)

Intuitively, what's happening here is that $S$ creates a left marker ($L_x$) and a right marker ($R_x$) which will eventually resolve to the same character. The left marker then expands to a sequence of $xW_x$ pairs, where $W_x$ is a "walker". The $W_x$s all walk to the right; when they finally hit the right marker, they deposit their payload *after* the right marker. This has the effect of creating two copies of the same string.

In an abbreviated form (combining derivation steps) you get something like this:

$$S\to L_aR_a\Rightarrow L_a b W_b a W_a R_a \Rightarrow L_a b a R_a b a \Rightarrow a b a a b a$$

Filling in the complete derivation would be a useful exercise. (Indeed, it's the exercise you've been asked to do.)