# generating strings from this formal grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

Hey guys I am having trouble generating strings from this language, I haven't seen a grammar that looks like this and can't figure how to generate strings from this grammar, is this Context Sensitive grammar? Thank you.

$G=(\{S, L_x,R_x,W_x \},\{a,b\},P,S) \\
P = \{ 
\\S \to \lambda \mid L_x R_x, \\ 
L_x \to x \mid L_xyW_y, \\
W_xy \to yW_x, \\
W_xR_y \to R_yx, \\
R_x \to x  \\\} \\
x, y ∈ \{a,b \} \text{ this means that } x=y  \text{ but also  it can be  } x \neq y
$

Comment: What do you mean that you're having trouble generating strings? Start from $S$ and apply the production rules until there are no more non-terminals. And yes, this grammar is context-sensitive as it can be seen by checking the [definition of CFG grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition).

Comment: Same grammar has been mentioned here [Derivation from grammar](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134771/derivation-from-grammar). The question has an answer there, but I am also curious: where does this quastion originate?